# Client disconnected during login

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

After updating our SQL Azure machines to v12 we get some wierd exceptions that we have not got before when trying to run commands against it.

```
Inner exception information (level 1):
    Exception type: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
    Exception message: Client disconnected during login
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

Is this something anyone else of you have got and how did you solve it?

Edit: We are having three regions EU, US and Asia. However we are only facing this problem in Asia.

Comment: The error looks transient and app should retry when you encounter such errors.

Comment: I can agree on that part. However we are only facing this problem in Asia region (we have EU and US region also) and no other region have that problem (and that database is even the smallest and not any load to talk about). So it still feels wierd and it would be intresting to understand why.

Comment: may be because of updates or some other activity on that region and you may see on other regions at later time?

Comment: I am seeing the same problem in the EU west center. My first occurence is at 2015-06-15 22:55 UTC and since then keeps happening intermittently. I think Azure is experienceing problems, but there is nothing on their service dashboard.

Comment: I noticed an interesting detail. The errors occur at very regular intervals, every 10-11 minutes, and last for about a second each time.

Comment: It turns out I didn't acutally use MARS, so turning that off solved the problem for me. There is a longer discussion about this on TechNet: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e81aef89-a65e-46c4-90bc-866af78d1526/after-v12-migration-sql-error-26078-client-disconnected-during-login

Comment: The problem seems to have been solved over the night. We did only  have the problem in Asia. Is it solved for you guys in EU-West also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a connectivity issue on the SQL Azure side. You should only be seeing the issue currently if you have MARS enabled in your connection string.

A fix has been identified and should be deployed very soon in the Asia data centers.

Answer (score 7):

Same problem here in EU west centre, the problem started as Johan wrote around 2015-06-15 22:55 UTC.
We've contacted Azure support and just got the answer «Wir haben aktuell Verbindungsfehler in unserer West Europe Region festgestellt» ie «currently there is a connection issue» but no further information on any solution or time frame when the problem will be solved...

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the update. Sneaky of them not to put it on the service dashboard. :-/

Comment: Same here and we are using SQL Azure in the EU West datacenter too; perhaps the issue is related to this datacenter only.

Comment: Same problem here since midnight in eu west. Changing connectionstring to not use multiple active result sets seems to help. But it should definitely be listed on the azure service dashboard.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Feels good to not be alone :) We have also started a support case with Azure.